# Collection+JSON deserialization into object

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

I'm having a problem deserializing Collection+JSON(http://amundsen.com/media-types/collection/format/) into an object using C# and asp.net

JSON format:
     `{ 
        "collection": { 
            "version": "1.0", 
            "href": "http://www.example.com/api/", 
            "links": 
                [{ 
                    "href": "http://example.com/api/issues", 
                    "rel": "issuesLink", 
                    "name": "issuesLink", 
                    "render": "link", 
                    "prompt": "All issues ordered by number" 
                }],
            "queries": 
                [{ 
                     "href": "https:\/\/example.com\/api\/search\/{field}\/{value}", 
                      "rel": "searchByField", 
                      "name": "FieldSearch", 
                      "prompt": "Search by field", 
                      "data": 
                             [{ 
                                "name": "name", 
                                 "value": "field" 
                             }, 
                             { 
                                "name": "value", 
                                "value": "" 
                             }] 
                 }]
           } 
     }`

I have no problems with using (or not using) JSON.net but haven't been able to get it to deserialize properly either way.  I have the JSON

```
public class FPResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("collection")]
    //I have tried using List<string> too
    // public Billboard collection executes the code but returns null for o
    public string collection { get; set; }
}

public class Billboard
{
    [JsonProperty("version")]
    public string version { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("href")]
    public string href { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("links")]
    public IList<LinkSet> links { get; set; }
}

using (var reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
{
    string rtn = reader.ReadToEnd(); //has the JSON string
    var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FPResponse>(rtn);
}
```

THE ERROR using JSON.NET: Additional information: Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path 'collection', line 1, position 15.

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`collection` is not a `string`

Your declaration should be as:

```
public class Link
{
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string rel { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string render { get; set; }
    public string prompt { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class Query
{
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string rel { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string prompt { get; set; }
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
}

public class Collection
{
    public string version { get; set; }
    public string href { get; set; }
    public List<Link> links { get; set; }
    public List<Query> queries { get; set; }
}

public class FPResponse
{
    public Collection collection { get; set; }
}
```

You may want to visit that site http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: Thanks @L.B I'll mark this answered when it allows me to.  I tried this previously but didn't setup every property.  I bet I needed everything for it to parse correctly.  Anyhow, your solution worked like a charm.  Thanks!